# how to convert excel expression INDIRECT("R"&(ROW()-1)&"C"&(COLUMN()), FALSE) into vba

Tags: excel, vba, macos

I'd like to use a concise function to get the value of up-cell or right-cell, anybody who can help me write down the vba function to achieve the excel expression  `INDIRECT("R"&(ROW()-1)&"C"&(COLUMN()), FALSE)` .

Thanks any help in advance.

Comment: I tried this `upCell = ActiveCell.Offset(-1, 0)` in function `upCell()` . however,  this solution get the result by value not by reference. That means if the up-cell value changed ,the cell use the function upCell() wouldn't update.

Comment: Don't convert that mess to VBA. First use the much simpler method - `Offset` - which works in both formulae and VBA, and then make sure you're using that to fill out the `.Formula` of your destination cell, not the `.Value[2]`.

Answer (score 0):

```
Function upcell()
    upcell = ActiveCell.Offset(-1, 0)
End Function
```

Worked for me. I put in cells A1, A2, A3 then numbers 1, 2, 3

Then in cell B3 I entered `=upcell()`

B1 was equal to the value of A3 i.e. 3
If I changed A3 to a value of 4 then cell B3 changed to 4.

Is this what you are trying to achieve?